# In High Chart x- Axis End data point Not showing correctly

Tags: highcharts

My example:`enter code here`http://jsfiddle.net/8wkyu9hh/

end-Data point should be Dec 2020. but it's showing Jan-2021.when set endOnTick: true, sep 2020 when endOnTick: false.
how to fix it.

Comment: The fiddle doesn't illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It won't show Dec 2020, because you have every third month displayed on the xAxis (Jan -> Apr -> July -> Oct -> Jun). I would upgrade your `tickPositioner`. Also, I would change `min` and `max` to use `Date.UTC()`, but this is just a personal opinion.

```
        tickPositioner: function (min, max) {
            var axis = this,
                options = axis.options,
                // get normalized tick interval
                normalizedTickInterval = axis.normalizeTimeTickInterval(
                axis.tickInterval,
                options.units),
                // get default ticks
                ticks = this.getTimeTicks(
                normalizedTickInterval,
                min,
                max,
                options.startOfWeek,
                axis.ordinalPositions,
                axis.closestPointRange,
                true);

            // register information for label formatter
            ticks.info = {
                higherRanks: normalizedTickInterval.higherRanks,
                unitName: normalizedTickInterval.unitName
            };

            // replace first label with 2004 year. When label overlap, remove for example first two elements (1 change to 2):
            //ticks.splice(0, 2, min);
            ticks.splice(0, 1);
            ticks.push(max);
            ticks.sort(function (a, b) {
                return a - b;
            });
            return ticks;
        }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8wkyu9hh/2/